# Blur effect in KDE Plasma disappeared

Tags: kubuntu, kde, plasma

I'm having an issue with the blur effect in KDE Plasma. I turned on my computer, and suddenly it just stopped working. I haven't changed anything of the configuration at all, so I think it was because of one of the updates installed today. I don't really know how to detect which one it was or how to fix it.

My `dpkg.log` file shows this:

```
2020-04-28 15:26:42 startup archives unpack
2020-04-28 15:26:53 upgrade python-samba:amd64 2:4.7.6+dfsg~ubuntu-0ubuntu2.15 2:4.7.6+dfsg~ubuntu-0ubuntu2.16
2020-04-28 15:26:53 status half-configured python-samba:amd64 2:4.7.6+dfsg~ubuntu-0ubuntu2.15
2020-04-28 15:26:54 status unpacked python-samba:amd64 2:4.7.6+dfsg~ubuntu-0ubuntu2.15
2020-04-28 15:26:57 status half-installed python-samba:amd64 2:4.7.6+dfsg~ubuntu-0ubuntu2.15
2020-04-28 15:26:58 status half-installed python-samba:amd64 2:4.7.6+dfsg~ubuntu-0ubuntu2.15
2020-04-28 15:26:58 status unpacked python-samba:amd64 2:4.7.6+dfsg~ubuntu-0ubuntu2.16
2020-04-28 15:26:58 status unpacked python-samba:amd64 2:4.7.6+dfsg~ubuntu-0ubuntu2.16
2020-04-28 15:26:58 upgrade samba-common-bin:amd64 2:4.7.6+dfsg~ubuntu-0ubuntu2.15 2:4.7.6+dfsg~ubuntu-0ubuntu2.16
2020-04-28 15:26:58 status half-configured samba-common-bin:amd64 2:4.7.6+dfsg~ubuntu-0ubuntu2.15
2020-04-28 15:26:58 status unpacked samba-common-bin:amd64 2:4.7.6+dfsg~ubuntu-0ubuntu2.15
2020-04-28 15:26:58 status half-installed samba-common-bin:amd64 2:4.7.6+dfsg~ubuntu-0ubuntu2.15
2020-04-28 15:26:59 status triggers-pending man-db:amd64 2.8.3-2ubuntu0.1
2020-04-28 15:26:59 status half-installed samba-common-bin:amd64 2:4.7.6+dfsg~ubuntu-0ubuntu2.15
2020-04-28 15:26:59 status unpacked samba-common-bin:amd64 2:4.7.6+dfsg~ubuntu-0ubuntu2.16
2020-04-28 15:26:59 status unpacked samba-common-bin:amd64 2:4.7.6+dfsg~ubuntu-0ubuntu2.16
2020-04-28 15:27:00 upgrade samba-common:all 2:4.7.6+dfsg~ubuntu-0ubuntu2.15 2:4.7.6+dfsg~ubuntu-0ubuntu2.16
2020-04-28 15:27:00 status half-configured samba-common:all 2:4.7.6+dfsg~ubuntu-0ubuntu2.15
2020-04-28 15:27:00 status unpacked samba-common:all 2:4.7.6+dfsg~ubuntu-0ubuntu2.15
2020-04-28 15:27:00 status half-installed samba-common:all 2:4.7.6+dfsg~ubuntu-0ubuntu2.15
2020-04-28 15:27:00 status half-installed samba-common:all 2:4.7.6+dfsg~ubuntu-0ubuntu2.15
2020-04-28 15:27:00 status unpacked samba-common:all 2:4.7.6+dfsg~ubuntu-0ubuntu2.16
2020-04-28 15:27:00 status unpacked samba-common:all 2:4.7.6+dfsg~ubuntu-0ubuntu2.16
2020-04-28 15:27:03 upgrade libsmbclient:amd64 2:4.7.6+dfsg~ubuntu-0ubuntu2.15 2:4.7.6+dfsg~ubuntu-0ubuntu2.16
2020-04-28 15:27:03 status triggers-pending libc-bin:amd64 2.27-3ubuntu1
2020-04-28 15:27:04 status half-configured libsmbclient:amd64 2:4.7.6+dfsg~ubuntu-0ubuntu2.15
2020-04-28 15:27:04 status unpacked libsmbclient:amd64 2:4.7.6+dfsg~ubuntu-0ubuntu2.15
2020-04-28 15:27:04 status half-installed libsmbclient:amd64 2:4.7.6+dfsg~ubuntu-0ubuntu2.15
2020-04-28 15:27:05 status half-installed libsmbclient:amd64 2:4.7.6+dfsg~ubuntu-0ubuntu2.15
2020-04-28 15:27:05 status unpacked libsmbclient:amd64 2:4.7.6+dfsg~ubuntu-0ubuntu2.16
2020-04-28 15:27:05 status unpacked libsmbclient:amd64 2:4.7.6+dfsg~ubuntu-0ubuntu2.16
2020-04-28 15:27:05 upgrade samba-libs:amd64 2:4.7.6+dfsg~ubuntu-0ubuntu2.15 2:4.7.6+dfsg~ubuntu-0ubuntu2.16
2020-04-28 15:27:05 status half-configured samba-libs:amd64 2:4.7.6+dfsg~ubuntu-0ubuntu2.15
2020-04-28 15:27:07 status unpacked samba-libs:amd64 2:4.7.6+dfsg~ubuntu-0ubuntu2.15
2020-04-28 15:27:07 status half-installed samba-libs:amd64 2:4.7.6+dfsg~ubuntu-0ubuntu2.15
2020-04-28 15:27:09 status half-installed samba-libs:amd64 2:4.7.6+dfsg~ubuntu-0ubuntu2.15
2020-04-28 15:27:09 status unpacked samba-libs:amd64 2:4.7.6+dfsg~ubuntu-0ubuntu2.16
2020-04-28 15:27:09 status unpacked samba-libs:amd64 2:4.7.6+dfsg~ubuntu-0ubuntu2.16
2020-04-28 15:27:10 upgrade libwbclient0:amd64 2:4.7.6+dfsg~ubuntu-0ubuntu2.15 2:4.7.6+dfsg~ubuntu-0ubuntu2.16
2020-04-28 15:27:10 status half-configured libwbclient0:amd64 2:4.7.6+dfsg~ubuntu-0ubuntu2.15
2020-04-28 15:27:10 status unpacked libwbclient0:amd64 2:4.7.6+dfsg~ubuntu-0ubuntu2.15
2020-04-28 15:27:10 status half-installed libwbclient0:amd64 2:4.7.6+dfsg~ubuntu-0ubuntu2.15
2020-04-28 15:27:10 status half-installed libwbclient0:amd64 2:4.7.6+dfsg~ubuntu-0ubuntu2.15
2020-04-28 15:27:11 status unpacked libwbclient0:amd64 2:4.7.6+dfsg~ubuntu-0ubuntu2.16
2020-04-28 15:27:11 status unpacked libwbclient0:amd64 2:4.7.6+dfsg~ubuntu-0ubuntu2.16
2020-04-28 15:27:11 startup packages configure
2020-04-28 15:27:11 configure libwbclient0:amd64 2:4.7.6+dfsg~ubuntu-0ubuntu2.16 <none>
2020-04-28 15:27:11 status unpacked libwbclient0:amd64 2:4.7.6+dfsg~ubuntu-0ubuntu2.16
2020-04-28 15:27:11 status half-configured libwbclient0:amd64 2:4.7.6+dfsg~ubuntu-0ubuntu2.16
2020-04-28 15:27:11 status installed libwbclient0:amd64 2:4.7.6+dfsg~ubuntu-0ubuntu2.16
2020-04-28 15:27:12 configure samba-libs:amd64 2:4.7.6+dfsg~ubuntu-0ubuntu2.16 <none>
2020-04-28 15:27:12 status unpacked samba-libs:amd64 2:4.7.6+dfsg~ubuntu-0ubuntu2.16
2020-04-28 15:27:12 status half-configured samba-libs:amd64 2:4.7.6+dfsg~ubuntu-0ubuntu2.16
2020-04-28 15:27:12 status installed samba-libs:amd64 2:4.7.6+dfsg~ubuntu-0ubuntu2.16
2020-04-28 15:27:12 configure python-samba:amd64 2:4.7.6+dfsg~ubuntu-0ubuntu2.16 <none>
2020-04-28 15:27:12 status unpacked python-samba:amd64 2:4.7.6+dfsg~ubuntu-0ubuntu2.16
2020-04-28 15:27:12 status half-configured python-samba:amd64 2:4.7.6+dfsg~ubuntu-0ubuntu2.16
2020-04-28 15:27:12 status installed python-samba:amd64 2:4.7.6+dfsg~ubuntu-0ubuntu2.16
2020-04-28 15:27:12 configure samba-common:all 2:4.7.6+dfsg~ubuntu-0ubuntu2.16 <none>
2020-04-28 15:27:12 status unpacked samba-common:all 2:4.7.6+dfsg~ubuntu-0ubuntu2.16
2020-04-28 15:27:12 status unpacked samba-common:all 2:4.7.6+dfsg~ubuntu-0ubuntu2.16
2020-04-28 15:27:12 status unpacked samba-common:all 2:4.7.6+dfsg~ubuntu-0ubuntu2.16
2020-04-28 15:27:12 status unpacked samba-common:all 2:4.7.6+dfsg~ubuntu-0ubuntu2.16
2020-04-28 15:27:12 status half-configured samba-common:all 2:4.7.6+dfsg~ubuntu-0ubuntu2.16
2020-04-28 15:27:13 status installed samba-common:all 2:4.7.6+dfsg~ubuntu-0ubuntu2.16
2020-04-28 15:27:13 configure libsmbclient:amd64 2:4.7.6+dfsg~ubuntu-0ubuntu2.16 <none>
2020-04-28 15:27:13 status unpacked libsmbclient:amd64 2:4.7.6+dfsg~ubuntu-0ubuntu2.16
2020-04-28 15:27:13 status half-configured libsmbclient:amd64 2:4.7.6+dfsg~ubuntu-0ubuntu2.16
2020-04-28 15:27:13 status installed libsmbclient:amd64 2:4.7.6+dfsg~ubuntu-0ubuntu2.16
2020-04-28 15:27:13 configure samba-common-bin:amd64 2:4.7.6+dfsg~ubuntu-0ubuntu2.16 <none>
2020-04-28 15:27:13 status unpacked samba-common-bin:amd64 2:4.7.6+dfsg~ubuntu-0ubuntu2.16
2020-04-28 15:27:13 status half-configured samba-common-bin:amd64 2:4.7.6+dfsg~ubuntu-0ubuntu2.16
2020-04-28 15:27:13 status installed samba-common-bin:amd64 2:4.7.6+dfsg~ubuntu-0ubuntu2.16
2020-04-28 15:27:13 trigproc man-db:amd64 2.8.3-2ubuntu0.1 <none>
2020-04-28 15:27:13 status half-configured man-db:amd64 2.8.3-2ubuntu0.1
2020-04-28 15:27:19 status installed man-db:amd64 2.8.3-2ubuntu0.1
2020-04-28 15:27:19 trigproc libc-bin:amd64 2.27-3ubuntu1 <none>
2020-04-28 15:27:19 status half-configured libc-bin:amd64 2.27-3ubuntu1
2020-04-28 15:27:20 status installed libc-bin:amd64 2.27-3ubuntu1
2020-04-28 15:28:15 startup archives unpack
2020-04-28 15:28:15 upgrade distro-info-data:all 0.37ubuntu0.6 0.37ubuntu0.7
2020-04-28 15:28:15 status half-configured distro-info-data:all 0.37ubuntu0.6
2020-04-28 15:28:15 status unpacked distro-info-data:all 0.37ubuntu0.6
2020-04-28 15:28:15 status half-installed distro-info-data:all 0.37ubuntu0.6
2020-04-28 15:28:15 status half-installed distro-info-data:all 0.37ubuntu0.6
2020-04-28 15:28:15 status unpacked distro-info-data:all 0.37ubuntu0.7
2020-04-28 15:28:15 status unpacked distro-info-data:all 0.37ubuntu0.7
2020-04-28 15:28:15 upgrade kmod:amd64 24-1ubuntu3.2 24-1ubuntu3.3
2020-04-28 15:28:15 status half-configured kmod:amd64 24-1ubuntu3.2
2020-04-28 15:28:15 status unpacked kmod:amd64 24-1ubuntu3.2
2020-04-28 15:28:15 status half-installed kmod:amd64 24-1ubuntu3.2
2020-04-28 15:28:15 status triggers-pending systemd:amd64 237-3ubuntu10.39
2020-04-28 15:28:15 status triggers-pending ureadahead:amd64 0.100.0-21
2020-04-28 15:28:15 status triggers-pending man-db:amd64 2.8.3-2ubuntu0.1
2020-04-28 15:28:16 status half-installed kmod:amd64 24-1ubuntu3.2
2020-04-28 15:28:16 status unpacked kmod:amd64 24-1ubuntu3.3
2020-04-28 15:28:16 status unpacked kmod:amd64 24-1ubuntu3.3
2020-04-28 15:28:16 upgrade libkmod2:amd64 24-1ubuntu3.2 24-1ubuntu3.3
2020-04-28 15:28:16 status triggers-pending libc-bin:amd64 2.27-3ubuntu1
2020-04-28 15:28:16 status half-configured libkmod2:amd64 24-1ubuntu3.2
2020-04-28 15:28:16 status unpacked libkmod2:amd64 24-1ubuntu3.2
2020-04-28 15:28:16 status half-installed libkmod2:amd64 24-1ubuntu3.2
2020-04-28 15:28:16 status half-installed libkmod2:amd64 24-1ubuntu3.2
2020-04-28 15:28:16 status unpacked libkmod2:amd64 24-1ubuntu3.3
2020-04-28 15:28:16 status unpacked libkmod2:amd64 24-1ubuntu3.3
2020-04-28 15:28:16 install glade2script-python3:all <none> 3.2.4~ppa23
2020-04-28 15:28:16 status half-installed glade2script-python3:all 3.2.4~ppa23
2020-04-28 15:28:16 status unpacked glade2script-python3:all 3.2.4~ppa23
2020-04-28 15:28:16 status unpacked glade2script-python3:all 3.2.4~ppa23
2020-04-28 15:28:17 upgrade glade2script:all 3.2.4~ppa17 3.2.4~ppa23
2020-04-28 15:28:17 status half-configured glade2script:all 3.2.4~ppa17
2020-04-28 15:28:17 status unpacked glade2script:all 3.2.4~ppa17
2020-04-28 15:28:17 status half-installed glade2script:all 3.2.4~ppa17
2020-04-28 15:28:17 status half-installed glade2script:all 3.2.4~ppa17
2020-04-28 15:28:17 status unpacked glade2script:all 3.2.4~ppa23
2020-04-28 15:28:17 status unpacked glade2script:all 3.2.4~ppa23
2020-04-28 15:28:17 upgrade boot-sav:all 4ppa85 4ppa93
2020-04-28 15:28:17 status half-configured boot-sav:all 4ppa85
2020-04-28 15:28:17 status unpacked boot-sav:all 4ppa85
2020-04-28 15:28:17 status half-installed boot-sav:all 4ppa85
2020-04-28 15:28:17 status half-installed boot-sav:all 4ppa85
2020-04-28 15:28:17 status unpacked boot-sav:all 4ppa93
2020-04-28 15:28:17 status unpacked boot-sav:all 4ppa93
2020-04-28 15:28:18 upgrade boot-repair:all 4ppa85 4ppa93
2020-04-28 15:28:18 status half-configured boot-repair:all 4ppa85
2020-04-28 15:28:18 status unpacked boot-repair:all 4ppa85
2020-04-28 15:28:18 status half-installed boot-repair:all 4ppa85
2020-04-28 15:28:18 status triggers-pending desktop-file-utils:amd64 0.23-1ubuntu3.18.04.2
2020-04-28 15:28:18 status triggers-pending gnome-menus:amd64 3.13.3-11ubuntu1.1
2020-04-28 15:28:18 status triggers-pending mime-support:all 3.60ubuntu1
2020-04-28 15:28:18 status half-installed boot-repair:all 4ppa85
2020-04-28 15:28:18 status unpacked boot-repair:all 4ppa93
2020-04-28 15:28:18 status unpacked boot-repair:all 4ppa93
2020-04-28 15:28:18 upgrade boot-sav-extra:all 4ppa85 4ppa93
2020-04-28 15:28:18 status half-configured boot-sav-extra:all 4ppa85
2020-04-28 15:28:18 status unpacked boot-sav-extra:all 4ppa85
2020-04-28 15:28:18 status half-installed boot-sav-extra:all 4ppa85
2020-04-28 15:28:18 status half-installed boot-sav-extra:all 4ppa85
2020-04-28 15:28:18 status unpacked boot-sav-extra:all 4ppa93
2020-04-28 15:28:18 status unpacked boot-sav-extra:all 4ppa93
2020-04-28 15:28:18 startup packages configure
2020-04-28 15:28:18 configure distro-info-data:all 0.37ubuntu0.7 <none>
2020-04-28 15:28:18 status unpacked distro-info-data:all 0.37ubuntu0.7
2020-04-28 15:28:18 status half-configured distro-info-data:all 0.37ubuntu0.7
2020-04-28 15:28:18 status installed distro-info-data:all 0.37ubuntu0.7
2020-04-28 15:28:18 configure libkmod2:amd64 24-1ubuntu3.3 <none>
2020-04-28 15:28:18 status unpacked libkmod2:amd64 24-1ubuntu3.3
2020-04-28 15:28:18 status half-configured libkmod2:amd64 24-1ubuntu3.3
2020-04-28 15:28:18 status installed libkmod2:amd64 24-1ubuntu3.3
2020-04-28 15:28:18 configure glade2script-python3:all 3.2.4~ppa23 <none>
2020-04-28 15:28:18 status unpacked glade2script-python3:all 3.2.4~ppa23
2020-04-28 15:28:18 status unpacked glade2script-python3:all 3.2.4~ppa23
2020-04-28 15:28:18 status half-configured glade2script-python3:all 3.2.4~ppa23
2020-04-28 15:28:18 status installed glade2script-python3:all 3.2.4~ppa23
2020-04-28 15:28:18 configure glade2script:all 3.2.4~ppa23 <none>
2020-04-28 15:28:18 status unpacked glade2script:all 3.2.4~ppa23
2020-04-28 15:28:18 status half-configured glade2script:all 3.2.4~ppa23
2020-04-28 15:28:18 status installed glade2script:all 3.2.4~ppa23
2020-04-28 15:28:18 configure kmod:amd64 24-1ubuntu3.3 <none>
2020-04-28 15:28:18 status unpacked kmod:amd64 24-1ubuntu3.3
2020-04-28 15:28:18 status unpacked kmod:amd64 24-1ubuntu3.3
2020-04-28 15:28:18 status unpacked kmod:amd64 24-1ubuntu3.3
2020-04-28 15:28:18 status unpacked kmod:amd64 24-1ubuntu3.3
2020-04-28 15:28:18 status unpacked kmod:amd64 24-1ubuntu3.3
2020-04-28 15:28:18 status unpacked kmod:amd64 24-1ubuntu3.3
2020-04-28 15:28:18 status unpacked kmod:amd64 24-1ubuntu3.3
2020-04-28 15:28:18 status unpacked kmod:amd64 24-1ubuntu3.3
2020-04-28 15:28:18 status unpacked kmod:amd64 24-1ubuntu3.3
2020-04-28 15:28:18 status half-configured kmod:amd64 24-1ubuntu3.3
2020-04-28 15:28:19 status installed kmod:amd64 24-1ubuntu3.3
2020-04-28 15:28:19 configure boot-sav:all 4ppa93 <none>
2020-04-28 15:28:19 status unpacked boot-sav:all 4ppa93
2020-04-28 15:28:19 status half-configured boot-sav:all 4ppa93
2020-04-28 15:28:19 status installed boot-sav:all 4ppa93
2020-04-28 15:28:19 configure boot-repair:all 4ppa93 <none>
2020-04-28 15:28:19 status unpacked boot-repair:all 4ppa93
2020-04-28 15:28:19 status unpacked boot-repair:all 4ppa93
2020-04-28 15:28:19 status half-configured boot-repair:all 4ppa93
2020-04-28 15:28:19 status installed boot-repair:all 4ppa93
2020-04-28 15:28:19 configure boot-sav-extra:all 4ppa93 <none>
2020-04-28 15:28:19 status unpacked boot-sav-extra:all 4ppa93
2020-04-28 15:28:19 status half-configured boot-sav-extra:all 4ppa93
2020-04-28 15:28:19 status installed boot-sav-extra:all 4ppa93
2020-04-28 15:28:19 trigproc ureadahead:amd64 0.100.0-21 <none>
2020-04-28 15:28:19 status half-configured ureadahead:amd64 0.100.0-21
2020-04-28 15:28:19 status installed ureadahead:amd64 0.100.0-21
2020-04-28 15:28:19 trigproc desktop-file-utils:amd64 0.23-1ubuntu3.18.04.2 <none>
2020-04-28 15:28:19 status half-configured desktop-file-utils:amd64 0.23-1ubuntu3.18.04.2
2020-04-28 15:28:20 status installed desktop-file-utils:amd64 0.23-1ubuntu3.18.04.2
2020-04-28 15:28:20 trigproc libc-bin:amd64 2.27-3ubuntu1 <none>
2020-04-28 15:28:20 status half-configured libc-bin:amd64 2.27-3ubuntu1
2020-04-28 15:28:20 status installed libc-bin:amd64 2.27-3ubuntu1
2020-04-28 15:28:20 trigproc systemd:amd64 237-3ubuntu10.39 <none>
2020-04-28 15:28:20 status half-configured systemd:amd64 237-3ubuntu10.39
2020-04-28 15:28:20 status installed systemd:amd64 237-3ubuntu10.39
2020-04-28 15:28:20 trigproc man-db:amd64 2.8.3-2ubuntu0.1 <none>
2020-04-28 15:28:20 status half-configured man-db:amd64 2.8.3-2ubuntu0.1
2020-04-28 15:28:21 status installed man-db:amd64 2.8.3-2ubuntu0.1
2020-04-28 15:28:21 trigproc gnome-menus:amd64 3.13.3-11ubuntu1.1 <none>
2020-04-28 15:28:21 status half-configured gnome-menus:amd64 3.13.3-11ubuntu1.1
2020-04-28 15:28:21 status installed gnome-menus:amd64 3.13.3-11ubuntu1.1
2020-04-28 15:28:21 trigproc mime-support:all 3.60ubuntu1 <none>
2020-04-28 15:28:21 status half-configured mime-support:all 3.60ubuntu1
2020-04-28 15:28:21 status installed mime-support:all 3.60ubuntu1
```

My system info:

```
Kubuntu 18.04
KDE Plasma Version: 5.12.9
KDE Frameworks Version: 5.44.0
64 bit
Processor: i5-7600K (no NVIDIA card )
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

KDE Plasma uses OpenGL for desktop effects, in this case the rendering backend was `OpenGL 2.0`. Apparently, it crashed and KDE disabled it.

Re-enable it manually going to *System Settings -> Display and Monitor -> Rendering Backend*

Comment: The setting is now under System Settings -> Display and Monitor -> compositor